# Strange issue while trying to read from a file with fgets()

Tags: c, input, buffer, fgets

I am trying to read from a file in C using `fgets()` however I have run into the following problem:

Although I can open the file successfully using `fopen()`:

```
if ( file=fopen(filename, "r") == NULL )
{
    printf("Couldn't open specified file. Please try again.");
    exit(1);
}
```

I can't read anything from it. I am using the following loop, although nothing is printed and the execution terminates successfully.

```
while ( (fgets(inputLine, 1023, file)) != NULL)
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

This is independent of the actual filename, filesize or file contents. Nothing seems to work and nothing is shown up as an error in the debugger. A sample file I have tried is the following directly copied and pasted:

```
test.txt
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
       printf("Hello World");
}
```

Do you have any guess as to why this is happening?

**NOTE:** I have taken the loop code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6255524/help-needed-regarding-the-segmentation-fault-at-the-file-pointer) S'O question so I guess it's right.

Comment: Don't forget to add a `\n` at the end of your message errors on `stdout` to flush the stream.

Comment: It should be flushed when the program terminates.

Comment: Could you show the entire program source?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: In the error message, the filename is far more useful than the string "specified file".  Try `perror( filename );`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
if ( file=fopen(filename, "r") == NULL )
```

Try:

```
if ( (file=fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL )
```

They way you have written it is equivalent to `file = 0` (assuming the file is succesfully opened.  If not, it is the same as `file = 1`).  This is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much. I am quite distracted at some times. I removed those parenthesis myself later and I forgot to put them back.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the fact you are doing a mistake in the condition of `fopen`, there is also a potential problem with snippets such as:

```
while ( (fgets(inputLine, 1023, file)) != NULL)
{
    printf("Hello world");
}
```

By default, the standard output stream `stdout` is *line-buffered*. This means that you should add a `\n` or a call to `fflush` to force the data to being effictively written.

```
fflush(stdout);
```